# For SEO perspective dynamic content good or not

Tags: seo, google-crawlers

i have 5 dynmic artcile in my home page, (random)

How quick google will read my content ,

First tell me Really Google will cron my content or not becoz am changes my content every page refresh ,

So i have this doubt ,

Google Will crawl random content Or Not ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask your question on http://doctype.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will crawl anything. But if your content is random you'll soon get a Google ban/discount. Regularly changing content is good, random content is not.

Also, your content is only a small portion of your search results these days. Getting relevant links (links from websites with domain authority) has much more influence.

Comment: PageRank has nothing to do with contents; it’s the valuation of outgoing and incoming links and their PageRanks.

Comment: but u see , if we use dynamic link , we are not giving the time for google to read the content bcoz very shortly we are changing the content no..so how google will read, assume if content is static , then google will read the content without any permission , but for dynamic it is not possible compare to static...

Comment: Indeed Gumbo, not for page rank directly. But for SEO (the other part) it is. I'll try to clarify.